# Открытие doc-файла

Tags: delphi

Ситуация: сохраняю текст из компонента `Memo1` в формате `*.doc` и потом при попытке открыть все успешно... но при попытке открыть файл такого же формата, но сохраненный не в приложении, выводится "абракадабра".

Код:

```
if not openDialog1.Execute then exit;
memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(opendialog1.FileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте открывать файлы блокнотом (Notepad) для проверки. 
Расширение файла не влияет на внутреннее содержимое файла. 
Формат doc не такой простой как кажется. 
От того что вы назвали файл как doc он не станет doc-файлом.
Memo может работать только с простыми текстовыми файлами.
Вы можете назвать свой файл в Memo хоть avi, но от этого он не станет фильмом, а останется текстовым файлом, но с расширением avi. И его можно будет снова загрузить в Memo. Но если загрузите в Memo настоящий avi, то у вас будет "абракадабра".
 Иногда Ворд может открывать неправильные doc-файлы.

Comment: ну я это в принципе знаю,лучше решение предложите)

Comment: http://trichview.ru/